# How can I make the contents of an #include-file a compile-time constant in a cpp-file?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, syntax, self-modifying

I have a file `module.hpp`

```
struct ModuleBase {
    virtual void run() = 0;
};
```

and a `main.cpp` program

```
int main() {
    cout << ...?...; // here should go the contents of module.hpp
}
```

**What can I put at `...?...` to let the contents of the header file printed here?**

A basic idea would be

```
int main() {
    static const string content = R"(
#include <module.hpp>
)";
    cout << content;
}
```

but multi-line-strings are only available in C++11, and `#include` does *not* work inside multi-line strings (which is good)?

If there is a non-portable way for the gcc... that would be a start.

**Clarification** (update): The substitution should be done at compile time.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way other then the one you used, unless you are willing to open the file using a stream and output it.

Comment: There _is_ a non-porbable way of embedding the header into the executable under Windows, but it won't work under other systems.

Comment: There's also a non-portable way with gcc.  You have the sources, so you can modify the compiler to do whatever you want.  (And yes, I'm being facetious.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Less facetiously, you could use `objcopy -O binary` to convert the header into an object file containing its contents.

Comment: MikeSeymour: Yes! Can you make the a full-blown answer, please? How to use/link the obj-files sysmbols from my C(++)-code then?

Comment: @towi Mike has given you the tip; if you're on Linux (or have access to the GNU binutils otherwise), the man page for `objcopy` should tell you all you need.  (From a quick perusal, I think the option you need is `-B`, and not `-O`.  But I've no real experience with it to be sure.)  Of course, Mike _should_ post it as an answer, since that's what it really is.

Comment: @towi: It's a while since I've done it, so I can't remember the exact heiroglyphs needed. I'll see if I can figure it out in enough detail to make an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only real solution I know is to write a small program which
converts a file into a C++ definition of a string variable
containing it.  This is fairly simple to write: output a simple
header along the lines of:

```
char const variableName[] =
```

Then copy each line of the file, wrapping it in `"...\n"`, and
escaping any characters necessary.  (If you can be sure of
C++11, then you might be able to do something with `R"..."`, but
I've no experience with this.)

*[update: refering to the original question with a typo in it]:*
Your solution should *not* work; if it does, it is an error in
the compiler.  According to §2.2, tokenization occurs *before*
the execution of preprocessing directives.  So when the 
execution of preprocessing directives occurs, you have a string
literal, and *not* a `#` preprocessing token.  (Compiler errors
are to be expected when using C++11 features.  There's not been
enough time yet for the implementers to get all of the bugs
out.)

Comment: I had a typo in my original question, no it does not work with Raw-Strings, of course. I corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

As a GNU-only hack, you could convert the header into a binary object file and link that with the executable.

First, use `objcopy` to do the conversion:

```
objcopy -I binary -O default -B i386 module.hpp module.hpp.o
```

replacing `i386` with the architecture you're building for if necessary. The resulting object file will contain symbols for the header contents and its size, which you can access as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

extern char _binary_module_hpp_start;
extern char _binary_module_hpp_size;

int main()
{
    char * header_start = &_binary_module_hpp_start;
    size_t header_size = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&_binary_module_hpp_size);

    std::cout.write(header_start, header_size);
}
```

Comment: I see. And during linking I just add the `.o`-file? And I do not have to handle symbol names inside the `.o`-file somehow? How is the connection from the linked `.o` to the symbol `_binary_module_hpp_start` and -`size` done? Those are introduced by `objdump`? Quite straight forward -- I like it. Someone has to hold me back from using this hack all the time ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from external tools, I think it cannot be done. The C++11 way you given does not work, `#include` is not expanded in a string. [See here for example](http://ideone.com/O8kC59).

The C++03 way *would have been* the following, with macros:

```
#define TO_STR__(...) #__VA_ARGS__
#define TO_STR_(...) TO_STR__(__VA_ARGS__)
#define TO_STR(...) TO_STR_(__VA_ARGS__)

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "String from #include <string>, ";
    static const char* str = TO_STR(
#include <string>
    );

    std::cout << sizeof(str) / sizeof(char) << " characters:\n\n";
    std::cout << str << "\n";
}
```

[With GCC](http://ideone.com/vpznRl), nothing is outputed. With Visual Studio 2010, `#include <string>` is outputed.

If you can modify the compilation chain, you can add a prebuild step which will include the contents of the file you want as a string (can be done easily with tools like CMake, or custom makefile).

Comment: The C++03 way hasn't changed in C++11.  But it doesn't give the
desired results either; §16.3.2/2 "[...] If the replacement that
results is not a valid character string literal, the behavior is
undefined" (and a valid character string literal cannot contain
a new line character), and §16.3.4/3 "The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not processed as a preprocessing
directive even if it resembles one."

Comment: Agree. I put "*would have been*", which I think is conditional and does not say that it "works". But as English is not my native language, I might be wrong...

Comment: I had a typo on my Raw-String explanation. I figured out that `#include` does *not* work in them. I corrected the question now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ofstream to open a file stream and read and output the contents.

Comment: And the way to do that keeping his syntax is using lambdas (see my answer).